# Problem with Node module on website

Tags: 7, nodes, users

Please bear with me on this one, as I am a complete newbie with Drupal, and am helping out a client on this one, so am trying to relay the problem they are having.

It appears that they are having trouble with a Node module, this module is used to add events and sell tickets to these events.

Currently when a new event is added by 'admin' it is only viewable by admin, so anonymous users can't see any see any events events. We think it has something to do with permissions or a between some modules, but as a say not really understanding the product i'm struggling to get to the bottom of it.

One of our developers also thinks that it could be something relating to a field used in the event, and user doesn’t have access to read this field (permissions).

It seems that for each there is a diferent permision filed in permisions section in admin panel.

Has anyone had this trouble before? Any help, ideas or even questions on this very  welcome. We may have to get someone in to finish this job off.

I may also have most of this backwards, so please ask if you need anymore info, or what I should look at and I can supply this straight back to you.

Thanks for the patience :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of permissions that could be affecting this.

First off, node permissions.  The most important one here is 'access content,' so make sure anonymous users can do that. After that, they can be set up so different users in different roles can create, delete and/or edit nodes.

Given that they aren't trying to do any of this, I doubt it's related to these node permissions, so let's go drill down a granularity level and look at permissions on fields in the nodes themselves.  Here, permissions can be set on edit and view.  Given they aren't trying to edit a node, just look at it, I'd look at the view permissions.

Assuming 'admin' is uid 1, s/he can do anything, so look for fields that aren't viewable by the more casual user/role.  Somewhere in there as you surmised above is the field that this module needs to show itself.  (Oh, also, if you are using imagecache, make sure its permissions are set up as well)

Comment: Hi Jimajamma, whats your background? would you be able to help us out of a tight spot?

Comment: If you're at 01******8696 I can certainly give you a call and see if I can help out over the phone talking you through some of the admin screens and such but much more than that, even though I know I am a good guy, I wouldn't trust just anyone from the interwebs (lol) inside my system :)

Comment: Ha, completely agree, I and getting the whole system moved today onto a new server. As soon as this has been done I will go over your pointers and maybe have to contact you over the next few days...